# $\int_Df(x+y)x^my^n d\lambda_2(x,y)^T=\frac{m!n!}{(m+n+1)!}\int_{0}^{1}f(t)t^{m+n+1}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the triangle with corners $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)$ and let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. How can I show that for $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$:

> $$\int_Df(x+y)x^my^n d\lambda_2(x,y)^T=\frac{m!n!}{(m+n+1)!}\int_{0}^{1}f(t)t^{m+n+1}dt$$

I'm thankful for any hints/tip/solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, $\lambda_2$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Then, we are to show
$$\iint_D\,f(x+y)\,x^m\,y^n\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y=\frac{m!\,n!}{(m+n+1)!}\,\int_0^1\,f(t)\,t^{m+n+1}\,\text{d}t\,.$$
Rewrite the required integral as
$$\iint_D\,f(x+y)\,x^m\,y^n\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y=\int_0^1\,\int_0^t\,f(t)\,x^m\,(t-x)^n\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}t\,,$$
where $t:=x+y$, noting that the Jacobian determinant of the coordinate transformation $$(x,y)\mapsto (x,x+y)$$ is $1$ (since the Jacobian matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$).  This shows that
$$\iint_D\,f(x+y)\,x^m\,y^n\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y=\int_0^1\,f(t)\,t^{m+n+1}\,\int_0^1\,\,s^m\,(1-s)^n\,\text{d}s\,\text{d}t\,,$$
where $s:=\dfrac{x}{t}$ (for $t>0$).  Use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) to show $$\int_0^1\,\,s^m\,(1-s)^n\,\text{d}s=\frac{m!\,n!}{(m+n+1)!}\,.$$

Comment: Thanks. $x^m=(st)^m=s^mt^m$ and $(t-x)^n=(t-st)^n=(t(1-s))^n=t^n(1-s)^n$. So I end up with $t^{m+n}s^m(1-s)^n$. Where am I missing the $t$ that is left?

Comment: You forgot $\text{d}x=t\,\text{d}s$.